# Validation group or display popup if textbox doesn't have a value

Tags: c#, checkbox, webforms, buttonclick

So I have a webform that has some buttons and textboxs which display calendarextender using ajax.
I want to set it up so that if a button is checked then the corresponding textbox with the calendar date needs to be choosen as well. I thought about using validation group but I don't want it to be on button click as well as not all textbox dates are required to be choosen along wiht their correspondng checkboxes.

Is their a way to do this on button.check or using javascript?

For example:

```
protect void main CheckBox1_Changed(object e event args)
     {
          if(CheckBox1.Changed)
             {
                 /*some kind of validation of date chosen*/
             }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two examples, one in C#, second in Jquery.  Both use Postback and display an alert.

via C#:
(HTML)

```
    <asp:CheckBox ID="chk" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
OnCheckedChanged="chk_Changed"/>
<asp:TextBox ID="date" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

(C#)

```
    protected void chk_Changed(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (chk.Checked && date.Text.Length == 0)   
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myScript", "<script language=JavaScript>alert('This is a test');</script>");
    }
```

Secondly this is using Jquery:
(Javascript using above controls)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
if ($('#chk').attr('checked')) {
    if($('#date').val().length == 0)
        alert('This is the Javascript check');
    }
});
```

**In each case you will want to set the checkbox controls AutoPostBack property to True**

To alter the text in the textbox you could use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var data = "Please enter a value!";
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('#chk').attr('checked')) {
        if ($('#date').val().length == 0)
            ($('#date').val(data));
    }
});
```

Comment: Instead of alerting them by popup can it display it in the textbox that is empty or next to it. Tried doing document.getelementbyid for the textbox name but couldn't find anything on how to do this.

Comment: See my edit.  To display it next to the textbox you could use a RequiredFieldValidtor control and reference that in the jquery script.

Comment: how do i reference thhe fieldvalidator in the script? when I add this in it displays the error message always i want it on button click

Comment: You could do the form validation from scratch, but I would suggest a jquery plugin if you want validation on seperate fields.  Here is a link to one I have used: [Jquery Validation Engine](http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/)

Comment: cool thanks for that but I found another way to do it but thanks for the answer to the original question!